# How to compile a python file to exe file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have the next code in a `.py` file with `tkinter` library that I want to convert into a `.exe` file to execute it in any Windows PC. When I convert it with `pyinstaller appname.py` it generates me the `build` and `dist` folders with the `.exe`. But when I execute it doesn't do anything.

`pyinstaller appname.py`
`pyinstaller -F appname.py`

```py
from tkinter import *
import os
import subprocess
import time

raiz = Tk()

######################################################################

raiz.geometry("380x560+700+200")
raiz.title('EVA APP')
#raiz.config(bg="white")
raiz.iconbitmap('robot.ico')

######################################################################

# LOGO DANI
imagen1=PhotoImage(file="robot_dani.png")
Label(raiz, image=imagen1, justify=CENTER).grid(row=1, column=3, pady=20)

######################################################################

# DEFINICIONES
def test():
    print("FUNCIONA")

def TV():
    subprocess.Popen(['//cpd-sts/UsersSoftware/TeamViewer_Setup.exe'])

def chrome():
    subprocess.Popen(['//cpd-sts/UsersSoftware/ChromeSetup.exe'])

def impromptu():
    os.system("start chrome http://cpd-reporting:9191/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Instalar%20Impromptu.aspx")
    time.sleep(2)
    os.system("//cpd-sts/UsersSoftware/IBMiAccess6Release1/DVD-1/Windows/cwblaunch.exe")
    time.sleep(5)
    os.system("%windir%/syswow64/odbcad32.exe")
    time.sleep(2)
    os.system("mkdir %userprofile%/Desktop/Cognos")
    os.system("xcopy //cpd-sts/UsersSoftware/Cognos/* %userprofile%/Desktop/Cognos /e /i")
    time.sleep(2)
    os.system("msg * Ir a las propiedades de Setup > Compatibilidad > Cambiar la configuración para todos los usuarios > Ejectutar este programa en modo de compatibilidad para Windows XP. Ejecutar Setup > Siguiente > Siguiente...")
    os.system("xcopy //cpd-sts/UsersSoftware/Webs_Feina/Impromptu.lnk %userprofile%/Desktop /e /i")

#######################################################################

# BOTONES
botonTest=Button(raiz, text="TEST", command=test)
botonTest.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky="e", padx=4, pady=8)

botonTV=Button(raiz, text="Team Viewer", command=TV, activeforeground="white", activebackground="#3399ff")
botonTV.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky="e", padx=4, pady=8)

botonChrome=Button(raiz, text="Google Chrome", command=chrome)
botonChrome.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky="e", padx=4, pady=8)

botonImpromptu=Button(raiz, text="Instalar Impromptu", command=impromptu)
botonImpromptu.grid(row=6, column=2, sticky="e", padx=4, pady=8)

######################################################################

# Ejecución del programa en bucle
raiz.mainloop()
```

The program should be executed with tkinter in a window but that window does not appear. It just does not do anything.

Comment: Have you tried to launch it with the command line `./appname.exe` ? You should get the error(s) on your terminal, can you provide it/them ?

Comment: Your code seems fine, it seems that you have some problem with your setup. Do what @Nqsir said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't put de `.ico` and `.png` images into the compiled folder hehe...

Comment: Okay, good, BUT the commands `pyinstaller appname.py` and `pyinstaller -F appname.py` aren't the good one. That would have been easier to tell us `pyinstaller -i icone.png appname.py`, I would have told you right away, not blaming, just saying ^^. Good luck